# eclipse android development, implementing json list

Tags: android, json, eclipse, list, arraylist

I'm working on an eclipse android project, it's a news app..
The objective is to display the list of news which I must import from an online JSON file and display that list in the activity
let's say I want to display the last 3 news..
and take this as an example : " http://www.tripoliscope.com/api/get_date_posts/?order=DESC&date=2014-07-08&count=3 "

How can I get some data from that JSON and display it in a list?
I've been searching for 3 days and no answer found.

Comment: Use JSONObjects and JSONArray to get values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we have some examples
Please go through this links

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944

Answer (score 0):

Go Through This Links

First **Read About JSON**

[JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

[JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)

**Go Through This Tutorial...**

[Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

[Android JSON Parser Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

[Parse JSON Data - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95)

This May Help You..

Answer (score 0):

jsoneditoronline.org/  to parse the json file online.It will show u how the json is encoded.Using that you can easily parse your data.Because then you will get a idea where u need to use JsonObject and JsonArray etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must follow Google Aquery json

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial-using-aquery/